# How can I implement a query that return a single record containing the informations contained in 2 specific record?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am not so into SQL and I have the following problem.

So basically I have a table containing the following fields:

```
id:                    BigInt
geographical_position: Geometry
// SOME OTHER FIELDS IRRILEVANT FOR MY QUERY
```

I want select a single record containg the **geographical_position** values of 2 specific record (have to be presented on the same record), so I try to do something like this:

```
SELECT
  a.geographical_position AS point1,
  a.geographical_position AS point2
FROM accomodation a

where a.id = 31 and a.id = 32
```

But it seems to be wrong because obtain an empty result set.

Basically I want to obtain the **geographical_position** of the record having **id=31** in a cell named **point1** and the **geographical_position** of the record having **id=32** in a cell named **point2**.

How can I do? What is wrong in my query? How can I fix it?

Comment: you mean `OR` not `and` no?

Comment: @Drew what do you mean?

Comment: for any given `a` alias row, a.id cannot be both 31 and 32 at the same time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do it with a `self join`.

```
SELECT
  a1.geographical_position AS point1,
  a2.geographical_position AS point2
FROM accomodation a1
JOIN accomodation a2 ON a1.id=31 and a2.id=32
```

The query you have currently is wrong as the `id` can not have 2 values at the same time.

Comment: Ok, it works fine. Now I was trying something like this but I didn't know that I can use the ON like a WHERE :-)

Comment: you should also look at narrowing down the `join` condition as all the records with id=31 are joined with all records with id=32. This can be huge if there are 1000's of records for each of them.

Answer (score 1):

Specify the table twice and reference accordingly:

```
SELECT
a.geographical_position AS point1,
b.geographical_position AS point2
FROM accomodation a, accomodation b
where a.id = 31 and b.id = 32
```